# File commands not working on XAMPP PHP server

Tags: php, xampp

I have set up XAMPP on a UNIX OS ie: Ubuntu. Any file command is not working properly ie: `file_exists`,`file_put_contents`. I am trying to create a login system whereby I am storing the login data in a folder called "Users". But on using `file_put_contents("Users/"+$user, $pass)` where $user and $pass is a valid string. It creates a file named 0 outside the User folder with the contents of the $pass. I have tried using absolute path but still am facing the same issue.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `+` operator is not used to concatinating, you must use `.` instead of that as

```
file_put_contents("Users/".$user, $pass);
```

or,

```
file_put_contents("Users/$user", $pass)
```

Comment: Sorry, I got so used to using python that I forgot. Will accept your answer soon.